# PHP getter and setter not quite what i need

Tags: php, getter

I would like to have the following:

```
<?php
class Context
{
    public static $ClientID = "";
    public static $ClientSecret = "";

    public static function RedirectURI()
    {
        return "http://" . $_SERVER[ "HTTP_HOST" ] ."/authenticate";
    }
}
```

**become something like this:**

```
<?php
class Context
{
    public static $ClientID = "";
    public static $ClientSecret = "";
    public static $RedirectURI;

    protected function getRedirectURI()
    {
        return "http://" . $_SERVER[ "HTTP_HOST" ] ."/authenticate";
    }
}
```

this will mean the API will be more intuitive and inferable when people wish to get access to the RedirectURI property:

```
echo Context::$ClientID;
echo Context::$RedirectURI;
```

Is there a way of doing this in PHP like you can in C#:

```
public class Context
{
    public static string ClientID { get; set; }
    public static string ClientSecret = "";
    public static string RedirectURI { 
        get 
        { 
            return "http://" . $_SERVER[ "HTTP_HOST" ] ."/authenticate"; 
        }; 
        set{} 
    }
}
```

I am aware of the __Get() but it seems you cannot then have an explicitly defined model because the property must not be set in order to act upon it?

```
<?php
class Context
{
    public static $ClientID = "";
    public static $ClientSecret = "";

    public static function __Get( $field )
    {
        switch( $field ) 
        {
            case "RedirectURI":
                   return "http://" . $_SERVER[ "HTTP_HOST" ] ."/authenticate";
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception( "Property {field} not defined" );
        }
    }
}
```

*Just to make life easier, `$_SERVER[ "" ]` cannot be used in property declaration... thus the issue.
I could make a global variable and reference it from the property, but I just don't like that approach.*

Comment: Using static for all this isn't great to begin with; all those concerns could be eliminated if you actually instantiated the class *or* gave up on the tiny bit of syntactic sugar and use `get...()`. I don't think accessing the property as property instead of by a defined function call is that much of a difference, but that's just me.

Comment: There's no really neat way to do it, but this is PHP... so you could use Reflection to modify the static property after the class decleration by including a little bit code in the file; it'll let you get around the inability to set expressions in statics.
(But it's still an ugly solution.)

Comment: Actually, static is perfect for this... but that's context that you could not have deferred from my question. Thanks for your responses guys, I think I will refer to a constant in the property declaration in this case.